# My app with PROCESS_TEXT intent does not appear in all apps' copy-paste menu

Tags: android, android-11, popupmenu

I am trying to extend the copy/paste menu to open a specific activity in my app.

The problem is, that my app appears in some applications, and in most of them do not.

AndroidManifest.xml:

```xml
<manifest ....>

 <queries>
        <intent>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PROCESS_TEXT" />
            <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
        </intent>
        <intent>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
            <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
        </intent>
        <intent>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <data android:mimeType="text/plain"/>
        </intent>
    </queries>

<application ...>

<activity
            android:name=".component.popupActivity.PopUpActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.Transparent.SemiBlack">

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.PROCESS_TEXT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
            </intent-filter>

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
            </intent-filter>

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <data android:scheme="http" />
                <data android:scheme="https" />
                <data android:mimeType="text/html"/>
                <data android:mimeType="text/plain"/>
                <data android:mimeType="application/xhtml+xml"/>
            </intent-filter>

        </activity>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Is there anything wrong with my implementation?

I have tested it with WhatsApp, Instagram, Facebook, FB messenger.
**Only works with Whatsapp**.

Other apps like **Translate**, **Outlook**, **idealo Shopping**, **Firefox Focus**.
was always able to add their apps to the copy/paste menu.

**Firefox Focus** is open source, I did not notice anything different in AndroidManifest.xml

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: One difference between Firefox Focus and your app is that their `PROCESS_TEXT` is handled by a dedicated activity, one with only the `PROCESS_TEXT` `<intent-filter>`. You might run an experiment to see if that makes a difference. Frankly, I cannot see *how* it would make a difference, but it is worth a try.

Comment: @CommonsWare, I have done the same, my activity has `PROCESS_TEXT` `<intent-filter>`.
I have also tested it without the <query> section. The results were the same

Answer (score 5):

After researching, I found the following:

This **intent-filter** must be added to the activity.
I have tested it with **Android 11** and **Android 12**.
*AndroidManifest.xml*:

```xml
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <data android:scheme="http" />
                <data android:scheme="https" />
            </intent-filter>
```

Comment: This actually works, thanks!
Any idea what does this intent-filter specifically do?

Comment: Upon further testing, I found that using `<data android:scheme="http" />` made it work for all of the apps I tried it with (Wikipedia, Instagram, WhatsApp, Gmail, Anki), but it didn't work for browsers (Chrome, Brave). After removing `<data android:scheme="http" />` and leaving only `<data android:scheme="https" />` it worked in all the apps previously mentioned and also in the browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the `PROCESS_TEXT` intent filter is at the top.

```xml
<activity
    android:name=".Navigation.HandleText"
    android:excludeFromRecents="true"
    android:exported="true"
    android:label="@string/action_translate"
    android:launchMode="singleTop">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.PROCESS_TEXT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
    </intent-filter>
    <intent-filter android:label="@string/action_translate">
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
    </intent-filter>
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        <data android:scheme="https" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

In my case I had two intent filters and moving the `PROCESS_TEXT` intent filter to the first position is what fixed it. Now it appears in Chrome, Samsung Browser and all other apps.